# Почему перестает работать toggle или click после подгрузки контента на ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Добрый день.

Пытаюсь сделать загрузку контента на ajax, знания ajax нет, но хочу разобраться, вероятно подскажите куда смотерть.
Не совсем понятно, есть 2 дива, в один выгружается контент во втором сайдбар, в сайдбаре меню, подгрузка контента производится аяксом, те нажал на меню в сайдбаре прогрузился контент в контентной части без перезагрузки страницы, но если в контентой части есть кнопка попапа, какой-нибудь тогл, он почему-то перестает работать после подгрузки аяксом, все клики и тоглы которые находятся вне контентной части работают а внутри нет, ошибок в инспекторе нет.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on  вместо `$(<element selector>).click(function(){ ... });` используйте `$(<parent selector>).on('click', <element selector>, function(event) { ... });`, где `<parent selector>` - определяет DOM элемент, живущий все время жизни страницы и содержащий элементы, определяемые `<element selector>`.

Comment: А, вопрос-то "почему"! При перезагрузке содержимого "контентной части" все элементы внутри нее уничтожаются и создаются заново. У новых элементов нет обработчиков событий, назначенных до перезагрузки.